# Creating a record based on check_box value using a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to create a reminder for a event with a check box. I'm using a nested form. An event has one reminder and a reminder belongs to the event. This is where I created the reminder:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :reminder, Reminder.new do |p| %>
   <label>Remind you?</label>
   <div class="form-group"> 
     <%= p.check_box :id %> 
     <%= p.label :id, "Email me 24 hours before the event" %>    
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

events_controller.rb

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
end
```

Right now I'm getting this error when I submit the form: [Record not found] Couldn't find Reminder with ID=0 for Event with ID=

The form works well when I don't use the checkbox. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: post your controller code for this action

Comment: Edit your question with the full code.

Comment: :id is the default primary key field...when u did Reminder.new , it will have nil id value

Comment: what fields u have in your model Reminder..? u shouldn't use id, how can u save boolean values in integer type :id..?

Comment: If reminder has no fields - you are counting on it's existence only - you may need to look for that checkbox manually in your create/update action and then before saving the event use something like `event.build_reminder`.  If you reminder *has* fields, you should put those in the form, not the :id of the reminder because when that form is rendered, the :id of Reminder.new is nil.

Comment: Reminder doesn't have any fields. How would I look for the checkbox manually in the controller?